# FPDF background color not changing

Tags: php, fpdf

Hi i am using FPDF i have some problem regarding setting background color.

currently i am using

```
 $this->_FpdfGenerator->SetFillColor('239', 0, 0);
```

also i have tried this

```
 $this->_FpdfGenerator->SetFillColor(239, 0, 0);
```

but background color is not changing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you take a look at the documentation, you have to give a green and blue component value to have your color.

Otherwise you will have a gray level.

[SetFillColor](http://www.fpdf.org/en/doc/setfillcolor.htm)

Comment: This answer is wrong. The OP did provide the Blue and Green Components as well as the Red component. A SetFillColor(239) generates a gray fill, I do not know but I assume that SetFillColor(239) generates the same color as SetFillColor(239,239,239). SetFillColor(239,0,0) generates a red fill color, not a gray scale.   I have seen FPDF fail to render a fill (alway white). I have also seen it work as documented. I do not yet know what causes it to ignore valid calls to the SetFillColor method.

Answer (score 0):

```
mpdf->SetFillColor('RED');
// Just Make the 7th Parameter Equal to TRUE 
$mpdf->WriteCell(38, 10, 'HeLLOO', 1, 0, 'C', TRUE);
```

Comment: it appears that you are referring to mpdf, not fpdf which the op is asking about. fpdf does not have a writeCell method that I am aware of.